# Is it possible for some singletons to outlive other singletons

Tags: android, database, singleton, android-room, dagger-hilt

In **android applications**, is it possible for some singletons to outlive other singletons?

To add more context, I am using hilt to provide my singletons. An example taken from my actual application.

```kotlin
...
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDatabaseValidator(
        @ApplicationContext context: Context
    ): XRoomDatabaseValidator {
        return XRoomDatabaseValidator(context)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDatabase(
        @ApplicationContext context: Context, 
        validator: XRoomDatabaseValidator
    ): XRoomDatabase {
        return XRoomDatabase.getDatabase(context, validator)
    }
...
```

`XRoomDatabaseValidator` validates the `XRoomDatabase` by having fields that is an anonymous implementation of `RoomDatabase.Callback` and `RoomDatabase.PrepackagedDatabaseCallback`; this fields are then used as callbacks in creating the database using `Room.databaseBuilder`

`XRoomDatabaseValidator` keeps some information about the `db`, like a `flag` that is set if the `db` was just created, or created from file, etc.

What I was worrying is if `XRoomDatabase` outlives `XRoomDatabaseValidator`, then `XRoomDatabaseValidator` now has the wrong information of `XRoomDatabase`; more specifically the initial values of the `flags`.